# what is the best way to upload bulk file on aws s3 using react and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-sdk, image-comparison

currently, I am uploading images using the "react-aws-s3" react module but I also want to check duplicate images with previously uploaded images. so I thought to upload images from the backend to overcome load on the frontend and apply images comparison.

files count could be 5000 or more at a time